# I'm trying to migrate the data from a table in a Azure DB to another table in a different AWS DB. What is the best way to achieve this?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-rds

I need to migrate the data from one table in Azure DB to another table in a different AWS DB. What is the best way to copy all the information from a table in one database to a table that resides within a different database?

I am using SQL management studio, and the option to script table results in the error invalid version 16 (Microsoft.SQlServer.Smo)

I could copy all the data in the table and add it into an insert statement. The problem is that I would have to format the data, which is subject to error manually. I do not have any former training on how to work with SQL. What is the best way to migrate the data? If anyone can assist, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade the version to latest, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your SSMS version is not compatible for this activity.
When I try with version 16, I got below error:

[image]

[image]

I upgraded the version and tried with 18.12.1 It worked fine for me.

Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The file created successfully.
Migrate Azure SQL database table from AWS database table create a .bacpac file using export option to azure blob storage.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

Copy the  `.bacpac`  file from Azure Storage to Amazon EC2 EBS storage and import the  `.bacpac`  file to Amazon RDS for SQL Server. In this way you can migrate the data of database from Azure SQL to AWS.